# Draw geographic coordinates on a world map

Tags: maps, geocoding

I have a list of 1.155 geographic coordinates (latitude & longitude, like 50.110555555556 & 8.6822222222222) and want to create a map out of them similar to this one: http://internetcensus2012.bitbucket.org/images/clientmap_16to9_1600x900.jpg
Just a small dot for every item in my list and the outline of the continents in the background. The software should generate a high res image (I don't wanna take a screenshot of Google Maps :) ).

I searched around and found Quantum GIS and GRASS GIS but I honestly have no clue how to work with these (I'm even not really sure if they're the right tools). I was able to make this image with Gephi https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFUmN.jpg but there should be a simple map in the background.

Anybody knows a simple tool which can help me?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: How big is your list?  1.155 or maybe 1.155million?  A list of 1.155 addresses would either round up to two or down to one.  Not a very big list.

Comment: Sorry, it's 1155 coordinates :) Here we use a point to separate thousands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [TileMill](http://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/). It is open source and has good [tutorials](http://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/manual/).

You can easily add markers to the coordinates by importing them as a simple CSV-file. Other options include KML, GeoJSON and ESRI Shapefiles.

It's also easy to tweak the appearance with CSS to get it to look exactly as you want it.

Comment: Thanks! TileMill is still in a quite early stage of development, but it helped me a lot: http://imgur.com/7KN8Mo8